# How to access nltk in pycharm?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I downloaded the nltk (book) using the code:
import nltk
nltk.download()

however when I try to test the nltk data using the below code, it won't work:
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown.words()

[image: the code and output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NLTK Window, navigate to the "Corpora" tab and check that `brown` has been installed. It should be highlighted green with status set to "installed" (see image below). Next check that you can find the unzipped `brown` folder in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data`. Finally, assuming everything is present and working (i.e. you're not receiving any errors) when running the code, you will not be seeing any output in PyCharm without calling `print`. Instead, try this:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
nltk.download()
print(brown.words())

# Output
>>> ['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', ...]
```

[image: NLTK Downloader Window]

Comment: ahhh i seee so it's because of print huhu thank you so much!!!

Comment: @adstrumm_ You're welcome, good luck with what you're doing!